# Не могу склеить path

Tags: java

properties

```
dir = C:\\Users
```

class

```
System.out.println("dir: " + properties.getProperty("dir"));
System.out.println("URL: " + url);
Path file = Paths.get(properties.getProperty("dir")).resolve(url);
System.out.println("path: " + file);
```

Вывод

```
dir: C:\Users
URL: /file/Новая папка
path: C:\file\Новая папка
```

Куда пропадает Users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите из `url` первый слеш. Если `url = "file/Новая папка"`, то все работает корректно.

Answer (score 2):

В описании метода [resolve](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve(java.nio.file.Path)) сказано:

> If the `other` parameter is an absolute path then this method trivially
>   returns `other`.

В переводе:

> Если параметр `other` является абсолютным путем, то метод просто
>   возвращает `other`.

Вы передаете в качестве параметра `/file/Новая папка`. Слэш в начале пути означает, что директория указана относительно корня, т.е. диска С - а это и есть абсолютный путь, поэтому метод и возвращает `C:\file\Новая папка`.